# Confusion about variable name in C++

Tags: c++

The following C++ code when compiled gives the error:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define IOS ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
#define endl "\n"    

const int N = 5005;

int n, k;
int a[N], prev[N];
int cache[N][N];

int dp(int idx, int take)
{
    if(take < 0)
        return -1e9;
    if(idx == 0)
        return 0;
    int &ans = cache[idx][take];
    if(ans != -1)
        return ans;
    ans = dp(idx - 1, take);
    ans = max(ans, idx - prev[idx] + dp(prev[idx], take - 1));
    return ans;
}   

int32_t main()
{
    IOS;
    memset(cache, -1, sizeof(cache));
    cin>>n>>k;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    sort(a+1, a+n+1);
    int l = 1;
    for(int r=1;r<=n;r++)
    {
        while(a[r] - a[l] > 5)
            l++;
        prev[r] = l - 1;
    }
    int ans = dp(n, k);
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}
//AshishGup
```

> Invocation failed [COMPILATION_ERROR] Can't compile file: program.cpp:
>   In function 'int dp(int, int)': program.cpp:23:23: error: **reference to
>   'prev' is ambiguous**
>   ans = max(ans, idx - **prev**[idx] + dp(**prev**[idx],
>   take - 1));

but as soon as the name of the array is changed from **prev** to **prv** it works fine. What is happening?

Comment: What's happening is an example of why ["`using namespace std;`" is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). You will do yourself a big favor if you completely forget that "using namespace std;" exists in C++, and always write correct C++ code. It only takes a short period of time before it becomes completely natural to always explicitly specify classes, templates, and functions in the `std` namespace, and, as an extra bonus, these kinds of mysterious compilation errors will go away, never to be seen again.

Comment: Most compilers give you more information than this in the error message. In particular, they tell you where the ambiguous names were declared. Error messages can be pretty dense, but wading through them can often give you enough information to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using namespace std;
```

It's [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1782465) to do that, and this is exactly why. There is ambiguity between your variable `prev` and the standard library function `std::prev`.

Also, you should [not `#include` internal compiler headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1782465) such as `bits/stdc++.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid importing `std` namespace into global namespace. In your case, you imported std namespace and you defined a global variable named `prev` which now will conflict with `std::prev` defined in iterator. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev